# How can I test if an event is dispatched in a model method

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I am writing a unit test with phpunit for my cakephp model. My model dispatches an event like this:

```
private function __dispatchEmailEvent(){
        $Event = new CakeEvent(
            'Model.Order.afterSaveCustomersOrder',
            $this,
            array()
        );
        $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($Event);
    }
```

What could I write in my test-function to check if this event was properly dispatched?

```
public function testEventDispatched(){

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways... one that I personally mostly use, is to register a listener and modify a referenced variable, which can be tested after invoking the action that is ment to trigger the event, something like

```
$model = ClassRegistry::init('TableName');

$dispatched = false;
$model->getEventManager()->attach(
    function (CakeEvent $event) use ($model, &$dispatched) {
        $this->assertSame($model, $event->subject());
        $this->assertEquals([], $event->data);
        $dispatched = true;
    },
    'Model.Order.afterSaveCustomersOrder'
);

$model->invokeWhateverTriggersTheEvent();
$this->assertTrue($dispatched);
```

* untested, requires at least PHP 5.4

Comment: This is correct. The name of the test case should be something like testEventDispatchedAfterSave(), and the trigger $model->afterSave().